# How to create pivot table from this data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I created a data frame with 2 columns that have random 1,0 value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = np.random.randint(2, size=1000).reshape(500,2)
data = pd.DataFrame(x ,columns=['x','y'])
data
```

How can I create a table (or another data frame) that looks like this:

```
     0      1
0  count count
1  count count
```

I think it has to be pivot table, but I can get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab):

```py
print(pd.crosstab(data.x, data.y))
```

Prints:

```
y    0    1
x          
0  132  134
1  115  119
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the solution.